# выделение голоса определенного спикера из wav файла

Tags: python

Подскажите как можно из звукозаписи, где говорят несколько человек выделить голос определенного?

Как я понял, здесь нужно использовать преобразования Фурье. Ну собственно оно и сделано. Есть частотно-амплитудная характеристика сигнала.

- Как понять какие гармоники мне нужны?
- Как их выделить и убрать лишние?

```
    def furieTransform(wav):
        s_rate, signal = wavfile.read(wav)
        FFT = abs(fft(signal))
        freqs = fftfreq(len(FFT), (1.0 / s_rate))
        plt.plot(freqs[range(len(FFT) // 2)], FFT[range(len(FFT) // 2)])
        plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.show()
```

[image: АЧХ]

Comment: Разделением по частотам нужный голос не выделить (разве что бас разговаривает с малышом). Эта задача вообще сложная. Формантный анализ и другие методы могут в какой-то мере помочь.

Comment: Задача и правда не простая. А вы попробуйте поотрезать частоты выше скольки-то или ниже скольки-то и послушайте, что будет с голосами :)

Comment: Есть еще одно соображение, котрое, возможно, может помочь. Мне встречалась подобная задача применительно к телефонии: разговаривают двое, как сделать распознавалку, которая отдельными фразами будет писать "секретаря" и "его собеседника". Оказалось, что проще научить asterisk писать отдельные "дорожки" на "входящий" и "исходящий" потоки - тогда в каждом потоке оказался только один собеседник